# Bootstrap fancy table doesn't work?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Again, some problem with bootstrap. I found excellent working on Fiddle [example HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/bobouch/Zf32B/) but now when I want to do that with my table it give me something like this  [HERE!](https://i.imgur.com/2vKxEzT.png). So it pop out it perfectly, but I cannot close it or enter anything in that field? Does any one know why? Also, I need to mention that I work with php, and a lot of 'echo'-es. I also try to include into php file only this code, without my table.

```
<div id='orderModal' class='modal hide fade' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='orderModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
<div class='modal-header'>
    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>x</button>
     <h3>Hajde bre vise!</h3>

</div>
<div id='orderDetails' class='modal-body'></div>
<div id='orderItems' class='modal-body'></div>
<div class='modal-footer'>
    <button class='btn' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>Close</button>
</div>
```

And still nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase css property z-index of #orderModal. Put it let say for 5000 or higher.

```
#orderModal{
    z-index: 5000;
}
```